# Help identify a component on VS-TY2662-V1 LCD driver board

Tags: pcb, components, identification

I just received what seems to be a faulty driver board for a 7inch LCD touchscreen. As soon as I opened the package, one of the components fell out of the static-protection bag. I'm now trying to determine what's going to cost me more: replacing this component on my own or sending the item back via international delivery.

This is the board:
[image: the driver board]

There are three of these, looks like an ear drum inside heat shrink wire wrap. Perhaps an inductor? The one that was torn off (bottom one) has an inscription: `600` followed by what seems to be the letter `V`, but only the `\` is visible. It has two leads that have been torn off. The board is produced by SainSmart and designated VS-TY2662-V1.

[image]

What is this component and what does the value inscribed on it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are inductors. The value on it is the maximum voltage the shrink wrap tubing around the inductor can itself handle, i.e. that value has nothing to do with the inductor.

The part, once you find out from the manufacturer what value you should be using, shouldn't cost more than a couple of dollars at worst so I'd consider contacting them and then repairing it yourself.

Comment: This explains why the remaining two inductors are unmarked. I'll follow your advice and contact the maker to find the inductance for the replacement.